# Collectd won't open listener

Tags: netstat, collectd

So I've been stuck with this for sometime now. I want to use `collectd` with `graphite`. Im using `centos 7`. I've made the necessary changes in `collectd.conf` as seen below:

```
[root@relay-1 ~]# grep -v "#" /etc/collectd.conf

LoadPlugin syslog
LoadPlugin logfile

<Plugin logfile>
       LogLevel info
       File STDOUT
       Timestamp true
       PrintSeverity false
</Plugin>

LoadPlugin cpu
LoadPlugin interface
LoadPlugin load
LoadPlugin memory
LoadPlugin network
LoadPlugin write_graphite
<Plugin network>
        Server "ff18::efc0:4a42" "25826"
        <Server "239.192.74.66" "25826">
        </Server>
</Plugin>

<Plugin write_graphite>
  <Node "example">
    Host "localhost"
    Port "2003"
    Protocol "tcp"
    LogSendErrors true
    Prefix "collectd"
    Postfix "collectd"
    StoreRates true
    AlwaysAppendDS false
    EscapeCharacter "_"
  </Node>
</Plugin
[root@relay-1 ~]#
```

No matter what I do I cant see a listener open for `127.0.0.1:2003`

```
[root@relay-1 ~]# netstat -tnlup | grep collectd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:44872           0.0.0.0:*                           20838/collectd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:59583           0.0.0.0:*                           20822/collectd
udp6       0      0 :::36059                :::*                                20822/collectd
udp6       0      0 :::51289                :::*                                20838/collectd
[root@relay-1 ~]#
[root@relay-1 ~]#
[root@relay-1 ~]# netstat -tnlup | grep 2003
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2003            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15868/python2
[root@relay-1 ~]#
```

`Carbon-relay` is listening on `2003`,

EDIT:
I would like collectd to bind to 127.0.0.1:2003 (so that it shows up in netstat). How can I do this?

P.S Carbon relay should continue listening on `0.0.0.0:2003`

Comment: "I cant see a listener open for 127.0.0.1:2003". That's expected behavior. Now, please edit further and ask your question, because you haven't yet. I think you also need to clarify whether you want to write to that `0.0.0.0:2003`, to remove it, or to set up a separate `127.0.0.1:2003`.

Comment: @kubanczyk I have edited my question. It was my understanding that the listener should open after making the above changes in `collectd.conf`, guess not. Thanks for the info.